# Reset SetConsoleCtrlHandler to close current console

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Hey I'm trying to change the SetConsoleCtrlHandler function in WINAPI to close the current console after I've set it to do another action.
`SetConsoleCtrlHandler(closeProg, TRUE);` this is what I did, it go to a function that terminates another process. and now I want to reset it to default.
Any help?

Comment: You call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(closeProg, FALSE)` to unregister your previously registered handler.

Comment: @Christian.K thanks man fixed my problem!

Comment: @justaman Hi, you can post an answer to end this thread.